# Not able to see single digit/letter as a term in after creating TermDocument Matrix

Tags: r, string, text-mining, term-document-matrix

I used `TermDocument` Matrix in R, and documents(strings) include single letter words also. After using `TermDocument` Matrix, the terms do not include those single letter words, please suggest which control should I include as an input argument in order to include single letter word in my term document matrix.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `min wordlength` is `3`. you need to specify the parameter as `control` to override the default, check out the following code.

```
library(tm)
docs <- c("This is a text","When Will u start", "1 12 123")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))

as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)) #words with length < 3 ('a','u','1','12') are excluded
#    Terms
#Docs 123 start text this when will
#   1   0     0    1    1    0    0
#   2   0     1    0    0    1    1
#   3   1     0    0    0    0    0

as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf))))
#    Terms
#Docs 1 12 123 a is start text this u when will
#   1 0  0   0 1  1     0    1    1 0    0    0
#   2 0  0   0 0  0     1    0    0 1    1    1
#   3 1  1   1 0  0     0    0    0 0    0    0
```